# NAS / Firewall, odd hardware config const. of Lenovo TD350 and HPE Microserver G10

Tags: file-management, backup

I am at odd here with my storage and backup solution. Currently I have two systems; an Lenovo TD350 with 4 / 2TB HDDs (RAID 10 2STRIPES)(2 NICS) and an HPE Microserver Gen 10 (2 NICS) with 4 / 2TB drives non-raid.

My current desire is to use the Microserver as my primary NAS/Backup solution while also using it as a secured firewall and router like ClearOS. The TD350 is currently being used as a Proxmox host.

Any operating systems or solutions would be so much appreciated. I dont wish to mess with ClearOS anymore.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be OK with Debian, because other rolling distros have too frequent updates, and you need something stable with easy upgrade process.

But if you need to change it to the NAS you may want to see openfiler or freenas.

Answer (score 1):

No config/set up info (superuser or unix.se) to keep it strictly on topic ...

For the OS I'd go with Debian stable (currently v10 aka "Buster").  I would use software RAID, and yes I do believe you could set up RAID-10 (I've only used -1 and -5).  Add a simple `iptables` script to set up NAT/firewalling.  Add `samba` for file sharing, LAN style, and perhaps something like `owncloud` for your mobile devices.